# Analysis of 3 power n and 3 power (n+1)

Tags: algorithm

Is `3^(n+1)` in `omega(3^n)` or in `theta(3^n)`? I found out that `3^(n+1)` doesn't dominate `3^n`.

Comment: 3^(n+1) = 3 * (3^n), thus, asymptotically no difference.

Comment: so 3^(n+1)=theta(3^n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3^(n+1) is in O(3^n) and in Omega(3^n) thus it is in Theta(3^n). As stated by Mr Ramzan Shan in the comments, the +1 in the exponent is merely a constant and therefore asymptotically unimportant.

It may be a good idea to go over the [formal definition of the big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), as it is a big help in categorising algorithms.